# Use NodejS API with Apache

Tags: node.js, express, apache2

I have a dedicated server to host my webapps.

I created a NodeJS app :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World! Node.js is working correctly.\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Then i created a virtualhost for Apache2 :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myServer.name
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

This command line : `curl myServer.name` return `Hello World! Node.js is working correctly.`

But in browser it does not work at all. (Connection refused)

What i missed ? Don't understand why it works on curl (and postman) but in browser ...

Thanks

**[UPDATE]** : Ping work only on my host machine (by ssh) Why ?!

Comment: What URL are you using with curl and what URL are you typing into the browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 curl http://apibd.yruama.dev and the same to the browser

Comment: Is it on Linux? Do netstat -lpano | grep 8080